# Missing help files for Microsoft.WindowsMobile in Visual Studio 2008 help system

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

I've just installed the Windows Mobile 6.5.3 DTK, both standard and professional. Before that I had the standard and professional Windows Mobile 6 SDKs.

All Windows Mobile help pages are missing in Visual Studio 2008's help system - in particular everything in the Microsoft.WindowsMobile namespace. Microsoft.WindowsMobile.DirectX is there, but it's not part of the Windows Mobile 6 SDK or 6.5.3 DTK.

If I open the WM6 docs from the freshly created program group, then it's all fine and dandy, but there doesn't seem to have been a proper integration with VS during installation.

Any ideas what's gone wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This SDK may not be in the default list of help collections.

In help, choose the 'unfilered' filter in the index tab, then type 'Visual Studio 2008 Combined Help Collection' in the 'Look for' edit box.

It will show you all installed help collections. You should see the WinMo collection and you can decide to include it in the default display.